# How does one define a set of common interactions with a data model in the MVP pattern?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvp

I've inherited a WinForms application which has significant issues surrounding separation of concerns between business logic and UI control. The two are so completely intertwined that UI modification/extension has become near impossible without introducing significant regressions.

One of the issues I'm facing as part of an MVP refactoring proposal is how best to define actions that affect our model. There are a lot of these actions (e.g, updating customer history) which are utilized in multiple areas of the application, so I don't want to code model interaction directly into the presenter.

A lot of actions that affect a given persistent object are already encapsulated within that object (albeit as static methods). Should I continue with this pattern, refactoring to make the methods instance-based, or split the methods off into a separate set of API-like classes?

**EDIT:**

What I'm really asking here is: is it okay to encapsulate methods affecting the model within the classes defining the model, or should I keep these POCO, and implement the methods in a separate set of classes which define an API to the model?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using MVP architecture, business logic and UI should not be intertwined. Because there is presenter sitting between business logic and UI. Presenter knows only interface of View, and Presenter subscribed to events of View. That's all what is known. You are free to changed controls on your View - arrange them, replace, change color - any UI stuff. And those modifications do not affect Presenter. And, of course those modifications do not affect business logic.

Now about Presenter. It just translates UI events to calls to Model, and then updates UI through IView interfaces. What calls to Model mean? It depends. It could be call to some service like WCF where business logic sits. It could be call to application or domain service object, or to repositories (in terms of Domain-Driven Design). But there should not be business logic. Presenter is simple translator of UI events to Model calls. It can create some DTO objects to assign them to View, but no real business.

And Model. Model is all those classes, which are called by Presenter. Here business logic sits. And business logic is not duplicated. If you need to update customer history, then it could be CustomerRepository, or some service object like SalesService. And that object is called by every presenter, which needs to update customer history.

Advice - do not use static methods for business operations. It tightly couples your objects. It makes testing impossible with standard testing frameworks. Use instance methods. Implement interfaces. Mock them. Your system will become loosely coupled and testable. Thats where benefit of MVP pattern becomes visible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm already aware of _most_ of what you have described: the switch to MVP forms the core of my proposal. I have edited my question to better clarify exactly what I am asking.